# Creating proxy_pass from cloudfront to ec2 instanse

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I'm want to create move our front end setup on CloudFront and s3.

I got an application with a static web site with an nginx that proxy_pass the host header to another port on the same machine (as seen in the code below).

```
location /api {
        proxy_pass http://my_app:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
  client_max_body_size 1000M;
  server_tokens off;
```

After I uploaded my frontend to s3 and configured CloudFront origin to go to the s3 static web server how do I configure the Origin Settings & Cache Behavior Settings to send the header to the ec2 instance as shown in the current Nginx config?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-at-the-edge.html ?

Comment: why do you suggest to do so with Lambda@Edge? isn't it meant for high volume of traffic?

Comment: It looks like Lambda@Edge can work with headers.